# shell directory access

Tags: catalina, xquartz

I recently upgraded to Catalina. I'm a bit of an old school Unix user, and I tend to use XQuartz/xterm/ksh.

Now that there are access controls everywhere, is there an easy way to add access to XQuartz/xterm? I've noticed that Terminal pops up a dialog to add permission, but in xterm it just fails.